# ArgoCD: no available registry endpoint: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, argocd

**Context**

A project is worked in a single GitLab repository, where each subproject contains its src/ folder, Dockerfile, etc. A similar structure is followed:

```
|_ sub-proj_1/
|_ sub-proj_2/
|_ sub-proj_n/
|_ docker-compose.yml
|_ .gitlab-ci.yml
|_ README.md
```

When the pipeline is launched, it is filtered by sub-project and the image is built with Kaniko, which is sent to the GitLab registry adding a custom path. The PROJECT variable allows to control sub-projects, i.e. sub_proj_1/, sub_proj_2/, sub_proj_n/ in the Gitlab registry.

```
publish_image:
  stage: publish_image
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - PROJECT=$(echo "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE" | grep -o -w -e "api" -e "frontend" -e "db")
  script:
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - echo "PROJECT=$PROJECT" >> build.env
    - /kaniko/executor --context $PROJECT --dockerfile $PROJECT/Dockerfile --destination ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/${PROJECT}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /.*api.*/ || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /.*frontend.*/ || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /.*db.*/)
      when: always
```

Images are uploaded to the GitLab registry without problems:

[image]

There are custom paths in the GitLab registry associated with each subproject:

[image]

[Gitlab container naming convention for container images](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/index.html#naming-convention-for-your-container-images) supports this kind of custom path.

The cluster has been added via: `argocd repo add https://git.xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.git --username xxx --password xxx`

[image]

**Issue**

The images are downloaded to a staging environment using a GitOps controller such as ArgoCD and this error is reported:

[image]

**Troubleshooting**

1. It has been tested with a registry where the path is not customized and the deployment is performed without problems.

[image]

2. Pulled the docker image in Kubernetes cluster VM, so it looks like the problem is in the GitOps controller:

[image]

3. To partially solve the problem, the tag has been merged with the custom part of the path. So if before the endpoint was `registry.xxx:443/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/db:c549f2b6`, now it is `registry.xxx:443/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xx:db.c549f2b6`. *This solution is partial, so I leave the issue open.*

[image]

**Question**

Any suggestions other than separating the subprojects (sub_proj_1/, sub_proj_2/, sub_proj_n/) into separate repositories, achieving proper authentication of the registry in ArgoCD?

Comment: Are you authenticating with the GitLab registry from the GitOps controller?

Comment: Yes, I have used docker login with Gitlab authentication token, and I have included a registration secret into helm chart deployment.

Comment: I have also authenticated the gitlab registry using the same  token via argoocd repo add.

Comment: are you able to deploy any other images from your registry via ArgoCD? As a test case I would first manually push an image to the reg and deploy it via ArgoCD. At this point it looks more like an authentication problem. The manually pushed image needs to be pushed with the same creds that kaniko uses.

Comment: Thanks @user1984, In the troubleshooting section I have just addressed that option. Basically, I have looked for another project with an image where the registry does not need an arbitrary path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved after trying to answer the following questions:

Could it be URL address resolving the issue?

I don't think so, because as mentioned in point 3 of the troubleshooting section. I have removed the custom part of the registry path and now it works properly. Using the same naming convention of [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/index.html#naming-convention-for-your-container-images):

- Failure: `registry.example.com/mynamespace/myproject/image:latest`
- Works: `registry.example.com/mynamespace/myproject:some-tag`

Could it be an authentication problem?

I want to think that this is because as mentioned in point 2 of the troubleshooting section, I can manually download the docker image from the cluster.

[image]
Could the failed deployment manifest be copied and applied to another namespace to check that is not a problem with cluster configuration?

As I am in the troubleshooting phase the way to test is via argocd from the VM where I have the GitOps Controller:

`argocd app create staging --repo https://gitlab.xxx/xxx.git --path charts/db --dest-server https://X.X.X.X:16443 --dest-namespace <name> --sync-policy automatic --auto-prune --self-heal`

After creating a new namespace in the same cluster the authentication works properly.